# Excel VBA: How to filter for the last value in the filter drop down?

Tags: excel, vba, autofilter

I have dates in column A formatted as such: "DDP_01_02_2018", "DDP_01_07_2018". 
I always have to filter for the latest date, which is always the last option in the filter drop down menu, would anyone be able to help me automate this, the last date is always constantly changing. 
I tried playing around with recording the macro, but of course that just picked the same selected date.

This is what I have so far:

```
Sub AddFilter2()
Sheets("Info1").Activate
Worksheets("Info1").Range("A1").AutoFilter _
 Field:=A, _
 VisibleDropDown:=True
???
End Sub
```

Edit: I used the code below from @QHarr, and it worked, however when I try to run the rest of my code I get an error message: *Runtime error 1004: AutoFilter method of Range class failed.*

This is the code where I get the error now:

```
Sub AddFilter2()
Sheets("Info1").Activate
Worksheets("Info1").Range("A1").AutoFilter _
 Field:=8, _
 Criteria1:=">7/31/2018", _
 Criteria2:="<1/1/2019", _
 VisibleDropDown:=False
End Sub
```

Any ideas?

Comment: How do the pieces of code fit together? Can you show some sample data including column and row headers?

Comment: Are you intending on filtering the same range on 2 different columns? How many columns are involved in total for the range?

Comment: The first column is the date in which the data for the rest of the columns in that row were posted. Column H is where I actually set the date range that I need to filter the data by.

Comment: Yes I am trying to filter 2 different columns within the same range. There are 11 columns total. It seemed to be working fine until I added the other filter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming not actual dates but strings as shown, you can use the last row value to set the filter.

```
Public Sub AddFilter2()
    Dim lastRow As Long

    With Worksheets("Info1")
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        .Range("A1:A" & lastRow).AutoFilter , Field:=1, Criteria1:=.Range("A" & lastRow).Value
    End With
End Sub
```

This assumes you don't have data underneath the filter range in column A. Otherwise, there are other methods to get the last row.

For example, if there are no gaps in the filter range you could use the following to get the last row:

```
lastRow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row
```

---

**PART 2: Multi-column filter (to reflect your update)**

I am not sure if your dates are actual dates. If they were, combining them might look like:

```
Public Sub AddFilter3()
    Dim lastRow As Long

    With Worksheets("Info1")
        lastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
        .AutoFilterMode = False
        .Range("A1:K" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).AutoFilter , field:=1, Criteria1:=.Range("A" & lastRow).Value
        .Range("A1:K" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row).AutoFilter , field:=8, Criteria1:=">7/31/2018", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<1/1/2019"
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the response! This worked, however it is now saying I have an error with a different filter I'm doing shortly after - this is the code for that filter: `Sub AddFilter2()
Sheets("Info1").Activate
Worksheets("Info1").Range("A1").AutoFilter _
 Field:=8, _
 Criteria1:=">7/31/2018", _
 Criteria2:="<1/1/2019", _
 VisibleDropDown:=False
End Sub` I didn't have this problem before, any suggestions?

Comment: I can't really follow that in the comments. I suggest you either 1) Add a new question or 2) Update the existing question to show the problem including all relevant code, error message and line where error occurs. Your filter range is going to need to encompass all the relevant columns and rows.

Comment: Sorry about that, I just updated the question so it's easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

Try the MAX of the column's values to get the latest date.

```
with Worksheets("Info1")
    .Range("A1").AutoFilter Field:=1, criteria1:=application.max(.columns(1))
end with
```